# Cherrypy expose multiple items to same function

Tags: python, cherrypy

I have a large number of names, which should link to url that correspond to their names. I know that I could do this by generating a function for each element in list and decorate it with `@cherrypy.expose`, I wonder however if it is possible to link the items instead to the function `function` without opening the same site for each item. (Something like generating an appropriate function on the fly, with a lambda function, and passing an appropriate argument?)

```
import cherrypy

class Test(object):

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self):
    html1 = '''<html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
            <ul style="list-style: none;">'''
    html2 = """</ul>
            </body>
            </html>"""
    html3 = ""
    for name in names:
        html3 += "<li><a href='%s'>%s</a></li>" %(name.lower(), name)
    return html1 + html3 + html2

  @cherrypy.expose
  def function(self, name=''):
    print(name)
    return name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the special method `default`:

```
import cherrypy as cp

class App:

    @cp.expose
    def index(self):
        return "This is the index"

    @cp.expose
    def default(self, name):
        return "Default with name: %s" % name

    @cp.expose
    def branch(self):
        return "Specific branch"

cp.quickstart(App())
```

You can try the urls: /, /branch, /ANY_OTHER_NAME. It can be defined even in a more generic term with a method definition like this:

```
 @cp.expose
 def default(self, *args, **kwargs):
     return "Default with args: %s and kwargs: %s" % (args, kwargs)
```

In that way you can accept pretty much anything. It will map the url parts into the `args` list and the query string into `kwargs`.